# Send selected cell index of CollectionView to viewController by segue

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, segue

I have a CollectionView. And I want to send selected cell index to ViewController by segue. For this I did:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("Cell \(indexPath.row) selected!")

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("categoryItems", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "menuItems"{
        var menuController = segue.destinationViewController as! MenuViewController
        if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UICollectionViewCell) {
            menuController.selectedCell = "\(indexPath.row)"
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't send anything. What is the problem? I just want to print it in the ViewController, where:

```
var selectedCell : String?

myLabel.text = selectedCell
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: Sender you pass for performSegueWithIdentifier is View controller not selected Cell. Alternative is create variable to hold selected cell index. After passing that value set it nil. Or use method indexPathsForSelectedItems to get selected index.

Answer (score 0):

You've a check with identifier

```
if segue.identifier == "menuItems"
```

and you're performing segue with this identifier:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("categoryItems", sender: self)
```

`menuItems` can't become `categoryItems` magically, you've to do something yourself :)

Comment: oh, damn it! But it prints the next error `Could not cast value of type 'CategoryViewController' to 'UICollectionViewCell'` in the next line `if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UICollectionViewCell) {`

Comment: That's because, you're sending `self` as `sender` while calling segue i.e `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("categoryItems", sender: self)`, you can pass `indexPath`. and get indexPath there. but that's not a good idea. Save the `indexPath` class-level is good idea or get the selected indexPath from your collection view.

Comment: so what do you advice me? How can I do it? Can you help me with it? I know how to do it for tableView, but not for collectionView

Comment: When you tap on any item, take the `indexPath` and save it to a class-level variable, then perform segue. While in `prepareForSegue` you can refer to class-level variable to pass to next view controller.